# JQuery convert string to Node Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to parse a string to an Node object. The following function should do something like this:

I want to get an input-element, embedded in an li-tag, whereby the input-element can be a radio-button or just a button. If the type is given as radio, a label must be added.

Unfortunately, the part:

```
inputElement = $.parseHTML(this.getFullHtmlTextOf(inputElement) + labelElement);
```

fails.

```
this.getKeyValAsInputInLiWithType = function (key, val, isArgument, type, isChecked) {
    var liElement, inputElement, labelElement;
    liElement = document.createElement('li');
    liElement.setAttribute('id', 'li_' + key);

    inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.setAttribute('id', key);
    inputElement.setAttribute('type', type);
    inputElement.setAttribute('value', val);
    inputElement.setAttribute('data-dismiss', 'modal');

    // additional attributes for a button
    if (type === 'button') {
        inputElement.setAttribute('class', 'button button-block btn btn-primary btn-default btn-discussion');
    }

    // additional attributes for a radio button
    if (type === 'radio') {
        if (isChecked) {
            inputElement.setAttribute('checked', '');
        }
        // adding label for the value
        labelElement = '\<label for="' + key + '"\>' + val + '\</label\>';
        inputElement = $.parseHTML(this.getFullHtmlTextOf(inputElement) + labelElement);
    }

    if (key === addStatementButtonId) {
        inputElement.setAttribute('onclick', "$('#'+addArgumentContainerId).show();$('#'+addStatementButtonId).disable = true;");
    } else if (type === 'button') {
        if (isArgument) {
            inputElement.setAttribute('onclick', "new InteractionHandler().argumentButtonWasClicked(this.id, this.value);");
        } else {
            inputElement.setAttribute('onclick', "new InteractionHandler().positionButtonWasClicked(this.id, this.value);");
        }
    }
    alert(this.getFullHtmlTextOf(inputElement));

    liElement.appendChild(inputElement);
    return liElement;
};
```

Kind regards,

Tobias

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Kindly refer the below link to parse the string to node object http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: Problem is, that the last statement, where liElement appends his child, fails with "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Comment: Okay, I've got a solution. I've commented the reassign "inputElement = $.parseHTML(this.getFullHtmlTextOf(inputElement) + labelElement);" and do not append the inputElement directy, rather I say "liElement.innerHTML = this.getFullHtmlTextOf(inputElement) + labelElement"

Comment: You've got quite the mix of general DOM methods and jQuery, with seemingly little logic between when one or the other is used. This will confuse you (and others) in the future. Pick a pattern and go with it. I would definitely suggest *not* using `setAttribute('onclick'...` to add event handlers. Use jQuery's `on()` method or the DOM's `addEventListener` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add two elements to one DOM element, and actually creating a string. Just append both elements to the li. You've tagged jQuery but there's no need for it for that one thing.

```
...
inputElement.setAttribute('data-dismiss', 'modal');

// now append inputElement
liElement.appendChild(inputElement);

...

if (type === 'radio') {
    ...
    // lose this // labelElement = '\<label for="' + key + '"\>' + val + '\</label\>';
    // this will just produce a string even if it worked // inputElement = $.parseHTML(this.getFullHtmlTextOf(inputElement) + labelElement);

    labelElement = document.createElement('label');
    labelElement.setAttribute('for', key);
    labelElement.innerHTML = val;
    liElement.appendChild(labelElement);
}
...
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qkjyxmf/5/)

It's cleaner to do all this with jQuery, but whatever works best for you.

---

Also, data isn't an attribute, even though it renders as one on page load. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but this had me confused at first too. The problem seems to be that jQuery returns the parsed element in an array even if there's only one element.

The solution is simply to access the correct array element.

Change

```
inputElement = $.parseHTML(this.getFullHtmlTextOf(inputElement) + labelElement);
```

to

```
inputElement = $.parseHTML(this.getFullHtmlTextOf(inputElement) + labelElement)[0];
```